# kafka gives Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a simple consumer with dead letter topic functinality by adding @RetryableTopic and @DltHandler method. It works fine in my local machine. Build correctly and application function correctly.

But in the a separate env when kafka and zookeeper are running in a sidecar, it gives below INFO log and the consumers stop.

```
2022-08-03 13:41:09.976  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.978  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.979  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2022-08-03 13:41:09.978  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.982  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.978  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Revoke previously assigned partitions xxx-0
2022-08-03 13:41:09.983  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx: partitions revoked: [xxx-0]
2022-08-03 13:41:09.984  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Member consumer-xxx-4-b9e92dbb-3726-48b1-8ff6-3e550c0956c9 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) due to the consumer unsubscribed from all topics
```

I'm new to kafka and i dont know what does above log means.

**Edit**

Since above log is not enough i added full log

```
2022-08-03 13:39:29.777  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Subscribed to topic(s): xxx
2022-08-03 13:39:29.777  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition xxx-retry-3000-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to 9cpZF_2cTs2Db0R0OYMtFA
2022-08-03 13:39:29.782  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Cluster ID: s28GwPkmTEOOKRkAUkwjWw
2022-08-03 13:39:29.784  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Discovered group coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2022-08-03 13:39:29.784  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Cluster ID: s28GwPkmTEOOKRkAUkwjWw
2022-08-03 13:39:29.785  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Discovered group coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2022-08-03 13:39:29.803  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] (Re-)joining group
2022-08-03 13:39:29.894  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] (Re-)joining group
2022-08-03 13:39:29.898  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] (Re-)joining group
2022-08-03 13:39:29.998  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition xxx-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to Pg5jHtdbRu-y3lfbrX23Kg
2022-08-03 13:39:29.999  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Cluster ID: s28GwPkmTEOOKRkAUkwjWw
2022-08-03 13:39:30.003  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Discovered group coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2022-08-03 13:39:30.073  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-08-03 13:39:30.076  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] (Re-)joining group
2022-08-03 13:39:30.075  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-08-03 13:39:30.078  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-08-03 13:39:30.083  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] (Re-)joining group
2022-08-03 13:39:30.083  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] (Re-)joining group
2022-08-03 13:39:30.098  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] (Re-)joining group
2022-08-03 13:39:30.173  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id
2022-08-03 13:39:30.178  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] (Re-)joining group
2022-08-03 13:39:30.278  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-03 13:39:30.474  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.w.e.e.EventHubAdaptorApplication       : Started EventHubAdaptorApplication in 40.773 seconds (JVM running for 44.671)
2022-08-03 13:39:33.089  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=25, memberId='consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2-1ad2ca33-d1a3-4626-8460-4008d8705cf2', protocol='range'}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.094  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=25, memberId='consumer-xxx-dlt-1-74310b12-d021-4bfe-b6eb-67d69fa99d68', protocol='range'}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.093  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=25, memberId='consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3-ed7c07c9-18a3-4edb-a3c1-cfac0e8b6448', protocol='range'}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.098  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Finished assignment for group at generation 25: {consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3-ed7c07c9-18a3-4edb-a3c1-cfac0e8b6448=Assignment(partitions=[xxx-retry-3000-0])}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.098  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Finished assignment for group at generation 25: {consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2-1ad2ca33-d1a3-4626-8460-4008d8705cf2=Assignment(partitions=[xxx-retry-1000-0])}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.098  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Finished assignment for group at generation 25: {consumer-xxx-dlt-1-74310b12-d021-4bfe-b6eb-67d69fa99d68=Assignment(partitions=[xxx-dlt-0])}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.113  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=25, memberId='consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3-ed7c07c9-18a3-4edb-a3c1-cfac0e8b6448', protocol='range'}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.115  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[xxx-retry-3000-0])
2022-08-03 13:39:33.119  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=25, memberId='consumer-xxx-dlt-1-74310b12-d021-4bfe-b6eb-67d69fa99d68', protocol='range'}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.120  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[xxx-dlt-0])
2022-08-03 13:39:33.124  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=25, memberId='consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2-1ad2ca33-d1a3-4626-8460-4008d8705cf2', protocol='range'}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.125  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Adding newly assigned partitions: xxx-retry-3000-0
2022-08-03 13:39:33.126  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[xxx-retry-1000-0])
2022-08-03 13:39:33.126  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Adding newly assigned partitions: xxx-retry-1000-0
2022-08-03 13:39:33.128  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Adding newly assigned partitions: xxx-dlt-0
2022-08-03 13:39:33.184  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=25, memberId='consumer-xxx-4-b9e92dbb-3726-48b1-8ff6-3e550c0956c9', protocol='range'}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.185  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Finished assignment for group at generation 25: {consumer-xxx-4-b9e92dbb-3726-48b1-8ff6-3e550c0956c9=Assignment(partitions=[xxx-0])}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.274  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=25, memberId='consumer-xxx-4-b9e92dbb-3726-48b1-8ff6-3e550c0956c9', protocol='range'}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.274  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[xxx-0])
2022-08-03 13:39:33.274  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Adding newly assigned partitions: xxx-0
2022-08-03 13:39:33.285  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Setting offset for partition xxx-retry-3000-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.282  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Setting offset for partition xxx-retry-1000-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.292  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Setting offset for partition xxx-dlt-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.299  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-dlt: partitions assigned: [xxx-dlt-0]
2022-08-03 13:39:33.303  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Setting offset for partition xxx-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}}
2022-08-03 13:39:33.304  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx: partitions assigned: [xxx-0]
2022-08-03 13:39:33.390  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-retry-3000: partitions assigned: [xxx-retry-3000-0]
2022-08-03 13:39:33.391  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-retry-1000: partitions assigned: [xxx-retry-1000-0]
2022-08-03 13:41:09.918  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Revoke previously assigned partitions xxx-dlt-0
2022-08-03 13:41:09.920  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-dlt: partitions revoked: [xxx-dlt-0]
2022-08-03 13:41:09.974  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Member consumer-xxx-dlt-1-74310b12-d021-4bfe-b6eb-67d69fa99d68 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) due to the consumer unsubscribed from all topics
2022-08-03 13:41:09.975  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Revoke previously assigned partitions xxx-retry-1000-0
2022-08-03 13:41:09.975  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-retry-1000: partitions revoked: [xxx-retry-1000-0]
2022-08-03 13:41:09.975  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Member consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2-1ad2ca33-d1a3-4626-8460-4008d8705cf2 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) due to the consumer unsubscribed from all topics
2022-08-03 13:41:09.976  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.976  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.976  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2022-08-03 13:41:09.976  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.978  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.979  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2022-08-03 13:41:09.978  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.982  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2, groupId=xxx-retry-1000] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.978  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Revoke previously assigned partitions xxx-0
2022-08-03 13:41:09.983  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx: partitions revoked: [xxx-0]
2022-08-03 13:41:09.984  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Member consumer-xxx-4-b9e92dbb-3726-48b1-8ff6-3e550c0956c9 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) due to the consumer unsubscribed from all topics
2022-08-03 13:41:09.985  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.985  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.986  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2022-08-03 13:41:09.988  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.988  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.979  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Revoke previously assigned partitions xxx-retry-3000-0
2022-08-03 13:41:09.988  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-retry-3000: partitions revoked: [xxx-retry-3000-0]
2022-08-03 13:41:09.988  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Member consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3-ed7c07c9-18a3-4edb-a3c1-cfac0e8b6448 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) due to the consumer unsubscribed from all topics
2022-08-03 13:41:09.989  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.989  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.989  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2022-08-03 13:41:09.984  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.989  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-dlt-1, groupId=xxx-dlt] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.990  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2022-08-03 13:41:09.990  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2022-08-03 13:41:09.990  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2022-08-03 13:41:09.997  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Resetting generation due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.997  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2022-08-03 13:41:09.997  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3, groupId=xxx-retry-3000] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
2022-08-03 13:41:09.997  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2022-08-03 13:41:09.997  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2022-08-03 13:41:10.073  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2022-08-03 13:41:10.074  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2022-08-03 13:41:10.074  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2022-08-03 13:41:10.076  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-xxx-retry-3000-3 unregistered
2022-08-03 13:41:10.077  INFO 1 --- [etry-3000-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-retry-3000: Consumer stopped
2022-08-03 13:41:10.079  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2022-08-03 13:41:10.079  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2022-08-03 13:41:10.080  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2022-08-03 13:41:10.084  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-xxx-4 unregistered
2022-08-03 13:41:10.084  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx: Consumer stopped
2022-08-03 13:41:10.085  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-xxx-retry-1000-2 unregistered
2022-08-03 13:41:10.085  INFO 1 --- [etry-1000-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-retry-1000: Consumer stopped
2022-08-03 13:41:10.087  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-xxx-dlt-1 unregistered
2022-08-03 13:41:10.087  INFO 1 --- [ner#3-dlt-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : xxx-dlt: Consumer stopped
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be related to the @RetryableTopic feature - if you run without the annotation you’ll probably get the same result from the main topic

Comment: yes, i also thought about it. But why i mentioned it in this question is that in the log it says consumer id as consumer-xxx-dlt-1. That is why is mentioned it. 

anyway what is the reason it shows above log as unsubscribed all topics or partitions ?

Comment: I don't really know - perhaps you can add more logs so we can have more context

Comment: @TomazFernandes i added more logs in the question. Please check it

Comment: Thanks Dushan. The container is stopping - does the app stop after that? Is the app running in a container / pod? Are the health checks properly configured?

Comment: yes, there are two sidecars (zookeeper & kafka). Pod is in running state but kafka creates the topics and it show the partitions for the topics and then it gives above log and stopped the consumers. Pod stays in the running state. 

Not sure whether i have missed some sidecar configurations.

Comment: I would double-check that. Also, can you look for logs that show the app is shutting down?